# Implement Home Button in custom Launcher

Tags: android, launcher, android-homebutton

I've written a custom Launcher and it works pretty nice. The Launcher has some pages filled with applications. I want to implement, that the variable that represents the page number is set to 0, if the homebutton is pressed. So if you are on a different page of the launcher and press the homebutton, you enter the starting page.
I've searched a lot, but couldn't find an answer that worked for me.
I've set the app as an launcher in the manifest.

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Is it possible to achieve this? Just change the value of one variable, if the home button is pressed and leave the rest of the home button, as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everybody who want to do the same thing. that's the way i solved it:
I added the following to the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true">
```

and wrote this into the java activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        final boolean alreadyOnHome =
                ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)
                        != Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        if (alreadyOnHome) {
            Log.d("whatever", "Home pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

I got it from here: [CyanogenMod trebuchet](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Trebuchet/blob/cm-10.2/src/com/cyanogenmod/trebuchet/Launcher.java)